# What does ((MPI_Datatype)1) mean in C++?

Tags: c++, casting, mpi, typedef

Could someone tell what exactly this means in C++?

```
typedef int MPI_Datatype;
#define MPI_CHAR           ((MPI_Datatype)1)
```

Is this a kind of casting?

Comment: it's `(int)1` (in parentheses)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a cast. A `1` by itself is of type `int`, but that cast makes it an `MPI_Datatype`.

This is a C-style cast. The C++ bindings for MPI were never all that complete and they've actually been deprecated now.

Comment: it's already `MPI_Datatype`, because that's an alias for `int`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath In this case sure. But the cast makes it more typesafe. It can lead to better compiler error messages. Also, another MPI implementation might use something other than int, so without the cast you'd have implicit conversions.

Comment: Also the MPI spec says that `MPI_CHAR` is an `MPI_Datatype`, whatever those are in a particular implementation.

Comment: The MPI standard only guarantees source level compatibility, i.e. mixing of binary modules linked against different implementations is usually not supported and therefore implicit conversions won't occur. On the other hand, in Open MPI `MPI_Datatype` is a pointer to `ompi_datatype_t` structure and `MPI_CHAR` is a pointer to the global variable `ompi_mpi_char` (a predefined instance of `ompi_datatype_t` that describes `char`).

Comment: Yes, simple blackbox abstraction layer. The user shouldn't know or care about what the implementation is.